# Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.AnalyzerBase+CollectAction failed

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm not able to install Microsoft Dynamics CRM EMail Router 2015 on my machine. I had an earlier version but however needed to re-install this.
I get an error as: "Action Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.AnalyzerBase+CollectAction failed"
How can I resolve this? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure you are following the steps in the [Upgrade CRM 2013 Email Router to CRM 2015 Email Router](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531069(v=crm.7).aspx) documentation.

> If you plan to upgrade both the Email Router and Microsoft Dynamics CRM, perform the upgrade tasks in the following order:
>   1.  Stop the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Email Router service. To do this, on the Start menu, type services.msc, and then press ENTER; or click Run, type services.msc, and then press ENTER. Right-click the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Email Router service, and then click Stop.
>   2.  Upgrade Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2013 to Microsoft Dynamics CRM Server 2015.
>   3.  Install the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Email Router:
>   If you already have the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Email Router installed, upgrade to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Email Router, as described below. 
>   If you don’t have the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Email Router installed, install the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Email Router, as described in Install Email Router and Rule Deployment Wizard.
>   4. You might need to restart the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Email Router service after the upgrade to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Email Router finishes. To do this, in the services list, right-click Microsoft Dynamics CRM Email Router, and then click Start.

The other thing I'd review if you haven't already is that you are meeting the [Microsoft Dynamics CRM Email Router software requirements](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699689(v=crm.7).aspx)

If you have done those steps already, I'd probably reboot the workstation/server and restart the install to ensure that there is not anything left in the temp files that could be conflicting with it (making sure to stop the CRM Email Router Service first if you are upgrading).  I would also review the Windows Application event logs for any errors related to the CRM Email Router Service and/or installation for additional details, although typically the installer is pretty good about being clear with regards to what is not working or is not expected.

One other item I'll call out is that you need to be running as a Domain user with local administrator privileges in order to install or to upgrade the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Email Router.